# YUI editor not giving output

Tags: yui

am using YUI editor plugins for rails( http://github.com/larsklevan/yui_editor) it render the editor but that is not giving me out put it just send blank field is there any way to manually
getting out put from editor and save that to textarea am using 2.8.0 YUI

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the event handler like

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on('submit', 'click', function() {
  myEditor.saveHTML();
}
```

If not then try with it.

if you have added this and still you are facing this issue then try with following,

Give id attribute for the button on which you have called the above handler.

I have tested it on in IE, FF and chrome.